# Get all category with post - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to get all category and category ID. And use this code to display:

```
echo '<li><a data-filter=".portfolio-'.$category->cat_ID.'" href="'.$cat_link.'">'
  . $category->name.'</a></li>';
```

I have 3 post in different category, but my loop give me 6 category name (2x duplicate).

```
<?php
$query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'parent'         => '',
    'orderby'        => 'id',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty'     => 1,
    'hierarchical'   => 1,
    'taxonomy'       => 'category'
);

$category_home = new WP_Query( $query );
if ( $category_home->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $category_home->have_posts() ) {
        $category_home->the_post();
        $categories = get_categories($args);
        foreach($categories as $category):
            $cat_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
            $cat_name= $category->name; 
            echo '<li><a data-filter=".portfolio-'.$category->cat_ID.'" href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$category->name.'</a></li>';
        endforeach; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you missed `wp_reset_postdata();` right after the while loop.

Comment: @DmitryS. i try wp_reset_postdata(); in different position in loop. This code does not help.

Comment: When i use:
`$categories = get_the_category($args);`
not
`$categories = get_categories($args);`


Then i have 3 category, etc. CAT 1, CAT 2, CAT 3, but when i have 2 entry in one category then i have CAT 1, CAT 1, CAT 2. But i want to have only once CAT 1.

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
   'orderby' => 'id',
   'hide_empty'=> 0,
   'exclude'   => 1, //Child From Boxes Category 
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
   $category_link = get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID );
   echo '<li><a data-filter=".portfolio-'.$cat->cat_ID.'" href="'.$category_link.'">'.$cat->name.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome that's wat i wanted!! i'm only change

`'orderby' => 'id',
 'hide_empty'=> 1,`